# ¿Cómo enviar datos POST a un servidor. en kotlin?

Tags: json, post, kotlin, eventos, onclick

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo enviar ciertos parámetros que tienen que ir de regreso al servidor si se hace hace el evento on?

> val store_id = 5463
>       val option = playsong
>       val play_now = true
>       val song_id = 163309

Estos son datos que tengo que regresar si se hace el evento on click y lo tengo que realizar por método POST y JSON, cabe recalcar que los datos que recibo vienen del mismo servidor y los visualizo en un recyclerview:

---

```
  @SuppressLint("Registered")
    class VolleySingleton : Application(){
        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
            instance = this
        }
        val requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
            get() {
                if (field == null){
                    return Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
                }
                return field
            }

        fun <T> addToRequestQueue(request: Request<T>) {
            request.tag = TAG
            requestQueue?.add(request)
        }

        companion object {
            private val TAG = VolleySingleton::class.java.simpleName
            var instance: VolleySingleton? = null
        }

    }
```

Esto es lo que llevo sin éxito.

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: Francisco, agrega actualizaciones a tu respuesta mediante la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/150680/edit)

Comment: ¿Algún avance? tengo un problema muy similar con Volley.

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
                Fuel.post("https://api.ejemplo.com/?option=algo", listOf("option" to "playsong", "store_id" to "1",  "play_now" to "true", "song_id" to developersList.song_id)).responseJson { request, response, result ->
                    val Bazinga = result.get().content

                    Log.e(TAG, "MENSAJE:  " + Bazinga)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                val Bazilon = e.message
                Log.i(TAG,"ERROR:  " + Bazilon)
            }
```

**Esta es la respuesta**

Comment: Si esta es la respuesta te sugiero agregar una explicacion. Revisar [answer].